# Can not import cv2 in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I have copied cv2.pyd file to python36-32/Lib/site-packages
help please!!

Comment: I am using opencv version 3.2

Comment: Where did you copy `cv2.pyd` *from*?

Comment: I have downloaded opencv version 3.2. After Extraction I copied file from opencv\build\python\2.7\x86\cv2.pyd to destination mention above

Comment: I asked because your error message looks *very* much like a 32-bit/64-bit issue. You almost certainly already know that  a `.pyd` is a DLL. 64-bit programs can't load 32-bit DLLs and vice-versa. So if the bitness is wrong, Windows will say the DLL isn't there, even though you can see that it is. From what you say, though, that appears not to be the problem.

Comment: What happens if you move the `.pyd` to `python36-32/DLLs`?

Comment: I have also copied to DLLs but it did not work.

Comment: Thanks @BoarGules I got the problem solve!! Actually, you were right, it was 32bit incompatible. Now i have installed python 3.6 64 bit and opencv3.2 whl file 64 bit itself. leads to well working..
Thanks once again.